# google-chrome headless mode, don't save output as a file

Tags: python, pdf, google-chrome-headless

I am going to use headless mode in chrome to render a pdf in server side. so i don't want to save the content as a file, i just want to save the content in a variable and return the content in my response. is there any option to do that in python.